# Federal early childhood education funding

Tags: data.gov, education

I'm trying to find a report of federal early childhood education funding levels by state, by year. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

ED.gov's State Fact Sheets on Proposed Federal Funding for Preschool for All is the report you are seeking. These reports are all about "Increasing Access to High-Quality Early Childhood Education", divided by state, and include federal funding data:
http://www2.ed.gov/about/inits/ed/earlylearning/increasing-access/index.html

Head Start Program datasets provide annual information on demographics, state allocations, program statistics, and general information on Head Start enrollment history:
http://eclkc.ohs.acf.hhs.gov/hslc/data/factsheets

Early Learning Initiative Awards
http://www2.ed.gov/programs/racetothetop-earlylearningchallenge/awards.html

Preschool Development and Expansion Grants and
http://www2.ed.gov/programs/preschooldevelopmentgrants/pdgfactsheet.pdf

Race to the Top–Early Learning Challenge (RTT-ELC) (since 2011) funding here:
http://www2.ed.gov/programs/racetothetop-earlylearningchallenge/2013-early-learning-challenge-flyer.pdf

CCD is an annual collection of fiscal and non-fiscal data about all public elementary and secondary schools, public school districts, and state education agencies throughout the United States.
http://datainventory.ed.gov/Search?seriesID=175
CCD home, more data
http://nces.ed.gov/ccd/

DOE's budget has a table comparing discretionary funding by state
http://www.nea.org/assets/docs/House-FY16-BR-Impact-on-ED-Discretionary-Title-I-and-IDEA_by_State.pdf

*not what you asked for*
this resource library has data, essentially comparing each state's performance (or lack thereof), as well as local government activities/spending and comparisons. Its actually really high quality data.
http://www2.ed.gov/about/offices/list/opepd/ppss/reports.html

Preschool Funding Trends by State Report:
http://www.nieer.org/publications/policy-reports/trends-state-funded-preschool-programs-survey-findings-2001-2002-2011
data:
http://www.nieer.org/sites/nieer/files/Trends%20in%20State%20Funded%20Preschool%20Programs_0.pdf
NIER publishes a Preschool Yearbook with state data comparisons:
http://nieer.org/yearbook